# When do `sort -k 2,3b` and `sort -k 2,3` differ?

Tags: sort, utilities

The [POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) of the `-b` flag for the `sort` command is

> Ignore leading  characters when determining the starting and ending positions of a restricted sort key.

I can understand the use for the starting position of the key, but what about the ending positions? Can anybody give an example?

For instance, with the locale set to POSIX, the file with content

```
x  z
x a
```

would be sorted differently under `sort -k 2` and `sort -k 2b`, but I haven't been able to come up with a case where, say, `sort -k 2,3b` and `sort -k 2,3` would make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has an effect when you add reverse to the comparison. Order of precedence are changed as in the `-r` only apply to *last-resort comparison*.

No reverse:

```
$ sort -k 1,2 sample
A  34
A 33

$ sort -k 1,2b sample
A  34
A 33
```

Reverse:

```
$ sort -rk 1,2 sample
A 33
A  34

$ sort -rk 1,2b sample
A  34
A 33
```

Comment: I'm still thinking about how it works, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I still don't see the rationale behind it. Why doesn't `sort -k 1,2b` alter the result in your first example?

Comment: @eze: When using `b` with `-r`, the `-r` only apply to *last-resort comparison*.

Comment: @eze: `sort -k 1,2b` has no effect. Field `2` is not left-trimmed.

Comment: Thanks again. Feel free to ignore me at this point :) but... wouldn't "last resort" apply to lines that are the same, or at least keys that are the same? In our examples the keys are different, and their meaning change precisely if `b` applies. I fail to grasp the motivation behind the design of this fine-tuned `b`, but I'll keep thinking about it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @eze: The meaning change, not the contents. Though at this moment I'm starting to doubt myself. Also, if you use GNU-sort, check out the --debug option. It can perhaps help ... had forgotten about that one.

Comment: Spending way too much time on this... POSIX says: "If any modifier is attached to a field_start or to a field_end, no option shall apply to either." So it turns out the appending `b` to the key in the second example above disables the "global" `-r`. I'm still puzzled about the use of the second `b`.

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody else is curious about this... and happens to find this question, Sukminder's mention of the `--debug` flag in GNU sort has helped me find an answer to scratch this itch. Suppose, as an admittedly contrived example, that you want to sort this sloppily formatted file:

```
x   FRA-Paris    Pierre
x ESP-Barcelona   Jordi
x     FRA-Nice  Charles
x    FRA-Toulouse Nicole
x   ESP-Seville  Javier
x    ESP-Madrid  Carlos
```

into this:

```
x    ESP-Madrid  Carlos
x   ESP-Seville  Javier
x ESP-Barcelona   Jordi
x     FRA-Nice  Charles
x    FRA-Toulouse Nicole
x   FRA-Paris    Pierre
```

That is, only paying attention to the country in the second field and then to the person's name, in the third field. We want to consider the first three characters of the second field, and it is important to ignore leading blanks when determining both the first character and the third character.

The command `sort -k 2b,2.3b -k 3b` would work, but `sort -k 2b,2.3 -k 3b` wouldn't. It must be said that in this case the most natural way would be to apply a global `-b` option, simply as `sort -bk 2,2.3 -k 3`.

Comment: Great. And good example. On the side: You probably is aware, but GNU-sort also has the *stable* `-s` option which can be very useful.

Comment: I didn't know about it until I looked into the `--debug` option. Thanks a lot for coming back! I don't want this site to issue me another warning that I shouldn't chat in the comments! Thanks a lot, Sukminder!